# Find green's function for $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}u+k^2u=f(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function

solve $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}u+k^2u=f(x)$, $k$ is not $0$, the boundary condition is $u(0)=u(1)=0$

First I set $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}g+k^2g=\delta (x-y)$, $g$ is the green's function.
the boundary condition is now $g(0,y)=g(1,y)=0$.
From this boundary condition, I get $$g(x,y)= \left\{ \begin{array}{l} 
B_1(y)sin(kx), 0\le x\le y\le 1
\\[2ex]
B_2[sin(kx)-(tan(k))cos(kx)], 0\le y\le x\le 1
\end{array} \right.
$$
Also, I have the following equation from $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}g+k^2g=\delta (x-y)$
$$[\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}]_{x=y-\epsilon}^{x=y+\epsilon}+k^2\int_{x=y-\epsilon}^{x=y+\epsilon}g(x,y)dx=1
$$
However, I calculate $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ and $k^2\int_{x=y-\epsilon}^{x=y+\epsilon}g(x,y)dx$ and get almost the same equation but one side is larger than another side by 1.
How do I proceed to find the green's function for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$\Big{[}\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}+k^{2}\Big{]}u(x)=f(x)$$
With
$u(0)=u(1)=0$
You set the equation for the Green's function
$$\Big{[}\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}+k^{2}\Big{]}G(x, y)=\delta(x-y)$$
Expand into the follwoing basis
$$G(x, y)=\sum_{n}g_{n}(y)\sin{\pi{n}x}$$
This gives
$$\sum_{n}\Big{[}k^{2}-(2\pi{n})^{2}\Big{]}g_{n}(y)\sin{\pi{n}x}=\delta(x-y)$$
Multiply by
$$\sin{\pi{m}x}$$
And integrate over $[0, 1]$
$$\sum_{n}\Big{[}k^{2}-(\pi{n})^{2}\Big{]}g_{n}(y)\int_{0}^{1}\sin{\pi{n}x}\sin{\pi{m}x}dx=\sin{2\pi{m}y}$$
Now, using
$$\int_{0}^{1}\sin{\pi{n}x}\sin{\pi{m}x}dx=\delta_{mn}$$
We have
$$g_{m}(y)=\frac{\sin{\pi{m}y}}{k^{2}-(\pi{m})^{2}}$$
So that
$$G(x, y)=\sum_{n}\frac{\sin{\pi{n}y}\sin{\pi{n}x}}{k^{2}-(\pi{n})^{2}}$$